# Can I hide or limit the items number of children shown in parent container?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a container that dynamically loads the tabs and items with API requests. I would like to lessen the number of tabs that display with it's being viewed on mobile or tablets. can I do this with media queries? [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/jsalgado582/pen/XWaPqZy)

```
<div id="catTabs" class="tab"><button class="tabTest" value="Moonwalks and Bounce Houses">Moonwalks and Bounce Houses</button><button value="Water Slides">Water Slides</button><button value="Obstacle Courses">Obstacle Courses</button><button value="Tents Tables and Chairs">Tents Tables and Chairs</button><button value="Carnival Games">Carnival Games</button><button value="Concession and Catering">Concession and Catering</button><button value="Concession Supplies">Concession Supplies</button><button value="Advertising and Promotion">Advertising and Promotion</button></div>

.tab {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #efefef;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need media inquiries

https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

```css
@media (min-width: 768) and (max-width:1024px){
 // css
  .tab{

    }
}
```